# Offload dart files to the cloud and use them in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to offload my Flutter code to the cloud to save storage space on the user device.  Is there any way I can use files from e.g. Firebase Storage in my Flutter app?

The reason is that I want to offer different minigames in my app that should be programmed in Flutter and don't want to have all files in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: It's important to understand that dart code is not included in app as-is.  As you can see in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#run-android), It's compiled ahead of time, and the compiled code is executed on the client.  Flutter provides no facility to dynamically load and compile source code at runtime.